# A generalized Monty Hall problem

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I am considering a generalized Monty Hall problem.

Let $D$ be a set of doors, $|D| \geq 2$. A car is behind one door, and goats are behind all the others. Instead of having to choose a single door as in the original Monty Hall problem, you choose a nonempty proper subset $A$ of $D$ out of which you would eventually like to choose one. (There are multiple doors that you suspect might lead to the car, but you cannot decide on one, so you say, “I’ll choose from this one, this one, ... and that one, but haven’t decided which.”) Upon your declaration, Monty, who knows which door has the car, reveals some doors as having goats. Let $B$ be the set of the doors revealed. Monty chooses $B$ so that $A \backslash B \neq \varnothing$ and $\overline{A} \backslash B \neq \varnothing$, where $\overline{A} = D \backslash A$ is the complement of $A$ in $D$. Now, you can maintain your original intention and make your final choice from (the remaining doors in) $A$, or change your mind and choose a door from outside $A$. What is your chance of winning the car in each case? The original Monty Hall problem arises with $|A| = 1$.

Here is my attempt.

Originally, the chance that the car is behind some door in $A$ was $\frac{|A|}{|D|}$. After Monty’s revelation, you have $|A \backslash B|$ doors left in $A$ to choose from, but the chance that the car is behind some door in $A$ remains the same. So the chance of winning the car by choosing a door from $A$ is now $\frac{|A|}{|A \backslash B|\cdot |D|}$.

On the other hand, the chance that the car is behind some door in $\overline{A}$ was originally $\frac{|\overline{A}|}{|D|}$. After Monty’s revelation, there are $|\overline{A} \backslash B|$ doors left in $\overline{A}$, but the chance that the car is behind some door in $\overline{A}$ remains the same. So the chance of winning the car by choosing a door from $\overline{A}$ is now $\frac{|\overline{A}|}{|\overline{A} \backslash B| \cdot |D|}$.

Is this correct?  Intuitively, this conclusion is somewhat hard to accept.

EDIT: Since I was asked to clarify how Monty chooses which doors to reveal, let's say we assume either Condition ($\alpha$) or Condition ($\beta$) given below (though they might mean the same). Note that $B$ could be empty. I would appreciate explanations as to how we end up with different probabilities without such conditions or under different conditions.

($\alpha$) $B$ is randomly selected from the set
$$
\{X \subseteq D \mid \text{ all doors in $X$ have goats}, A \backslash X \neq \varnothing \text{ and } \overline{A} \backslash X \neq \varnothing  \}.
$$
That is, all elements of this set have an equal chance of being selected by Monty.

($\beta$) All *revealable* doors have an equal chance of being included in $B$, where a *revealable* door is a door $x$ such that (i) $x$ has a goat, (ii) $A \neq \{x\}$ and (iii) $\overline{A} \neq \{x\}$.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things a bit. The principle that your chances are the size of your set of choice divided by the size of the total set remains true. So the chance of winning the car now by selecting a door from $A$ is $|A\setminus B|/|D\setminus B|$ and the chance by selecting a door from $\bar{A}$ is $|\bar{A}\setminus B|/|D\setminus B|$.

Comment: Not sure your rules are clear.  You need to specify exactly how Monty chooses which (and how many) doors to open.  This issue comes up even in the standard problem though it is frequently ignored (mostly because its kind of obvious that he is meant to choose uniformly between the two unselected doors if both are worthless).

Comment: @Bellmunt I don't think so. Applying your logic to the original Monty Hall problem, the chance of getting the car with the original choice would be 1/2, rather than the correct 1/3. Think of an extreme case. Suppose that $|D| = 100$, $|A| = 99$, $B \subseteq A$ with $|B| = 98$ in my problem. I think it is pretty clear that the chance of getting the car by choosing the single door left in $A$ is 99%, and not 1/2.

Comment: @lulu It seems to me that how Monty chooses doors doesn't matter as long as it cannot be guessed by the player. I am pretty ignorant of probability theory, so if this point matters, I would appreciate an answer that explains how it matters and how you end up with different probabilities.

Comment: If it hasn't been clear, Monty, who knows where the car is, purposely chooses only doors with goats.

Comment: You need to specify the rule he follows. In the standard problem, suppose he could sometimes open *both* of the unselected doors.  Then, if he did that, you'd know you had the right one.  And if he only opened one, well, perhaps he did that because he couldn't open the one he didn't open.  In other variants, including yours, the rules are not obvious so you have to state them precisely.  Many choices are possible.

Comment: @lulu The only rule I have in mind is that Monty can choose any subset $B$ of $D$ as long as $A \backslash B \neq \varnothing$, $\overline{A} \backslash B \neq \varnothing$, and the car is not behind any door in $B$. $|B|$ can be 1, 2 or anything at Monty's whim. If anything more regarding the rule matters or if a slight change of the rule leads to a different result, I would like to see an answer that explains it.

Comment: Not good enough.  We need to know what factors determine his "whim".  If you want to compute probabilities, that is.  If you aren't trying to compute anything, then you can be vague about the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a game under Condition ($\alpha$)
with four numbered doors, $D = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}.$

Suppose you initially choose $A = \{1, 2, 3\}.$
Let's repeat this game many times, making the same choice of $A$ each time.

In the long run, in $3/4$ of the games the car will be behind a door in set $A,$
and Monty has three choices for set $B.$
For example, if the car is behind door $1,$ then $B \in \{\{2\}, \{3\}, \{2,3\}\}.$
In that particular case Monty chooses to open one door with probability $2/3,$
two doors with probability $1/3.$
The same holds when the car is behind another door in $A,$ so altogether, in $1/4$ of all games Monty will open two doors and the car will be behind the only remaining unopened door in set $A.$ Any set of two doors in set $A$ is equally likely to be opened.

Also in the long run, in $1/4$ of the games the car will be behind door $4.$
Then $B \in \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}\}.$
Monty will open two doors with probability $1/2$ in that case,
so in $1/8$ of all games Monty will open two doors and the car will be behind door $4$. Again, any set of two doors in set $A$ is equally likely to be opened.

In the other $5/8$ of the games Monty opens only one door.

Therefore, if you have gotten to the stage where Monty has opened the doors in set $B$ and you can still make a final choice,
and if in this particular game $\lvert B\rvert = 2,$
by Bayes' Theorem the conditional probability that the car is behind the only remaining door in $A \setminus B$ (given all these circumstances) is $2/3.$
But

$$ \frac{\lvert A\rvert}{\lvert A \setminus B\rvert\cdot \lvert D\rvert} 
 = \frac{3}{1\cdot 4} = \frac34,
$$

so the alleged formula does not hold for this decision point; it overestimates the conditional probability of winning by picking a door from set $A.$

On the other hand, a similar analysis of the cases where Monty opens only one door shows that when $\lvert B\rvert = 1,$
the conditional probability that the car is behind one of the two remaining doors in
$A \setminus B$ (given all these circumstances) is $4/5.$
That is, $2/5$ for one door in $A \setminus B$ and $2/5$ for the other door in
$A \setminus B$, whereas

$$ \frac{\lvert A\rvert}{\lvert A \setminus B\rvert\cdot \lvert D\rvert} 
 = \frac{3}{2\cdot 4} = \frac38.
$$

In this case, this formula *under*estimates the conditional probability of winning by picking a door from set $A.$

---

If $B$ can be the empty set with the same probability as any other permitted set, then (continuing the example above) if the car is in $A$ then Monty opens two doors with probability $1/4,$ so this occurs in $3/16$ of all games. If the car is behind door $4$ then Monty opens two doors with probability $3/7,$ and this happens in $3/28$ of all games.
So given that Monty opened two doors, the car is in $A$ with probability
$$
\frac{3/16}{3/16 + 3/28} = \frac{7}{11} < \frac34.
$$
The case where the car is in $A$ and Monty opens no doors occurs in $3/16$ of all games and the case where the car is behind door $4$ and Monty opens no doors occurs in $1/28$ of all games, and
$$
\frac{3/16}{3/16 + 1/28} = \frac{21}{25} > \frac34,
$$
so the fact that Monty "does nothing at all" is actually information about where the car is.

---

It is possible to make the formula work by changing how Monty chooses the doors to open. For example, if you are playing with four doors, you choose $\lvert A\rvert=3,$ and he always opens two doors, the formula gives the correct probability $3/4$ that the car is behind the remaining unopened door in set $A.$

I think (though I have not proved) that if Monty always opens exactly $n$ doors, where $n$ is some fixed number such that
$0 \leq n \leq \lvert D\rvert - 2,$
that the formula in the question will then give the correct probabilities.
The intuitive reasoning behind this is that the reason for the different probabilities in the examples earlier in this question is that the probability of choosing $n$ doors (for some particular $n$) is different when the car is in $A$ than when the car is in $\bar A.$
If the probabilities are both $1$ then this effect should disappear.

Comment: Thank you. I have not studied your answer throughly yet, but I am assuming that Monty could choose $B = \varnothing$, and you seem to have excluded that possibility.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very detailed answer. Since you have assumed $B \neq \varnothing$, I have taken into consideration the possibility that $B = \varnothing$ and followed your argument. Then, in the case where $|B| = 2$, the conditional probability that the car is behind the only remaining door in $A \backslash B$ is $7/11$, and in the case where $|B| = 1$, the conditional probability that the car is behind one of the two doors in $A \backslash B$ is $7/9$, so we have a $7/18$ chance for each door. This also teaches me that how Monty chooses $B$ affects the probabilities in question.

Comment: Now, my first remaining question is, if there is some number $n$ such that Monty always chooses $n$ doors, i.e., if he randomly chooses from the set
$$
\{X \subseteq D \mid |X| = n, \text{ all doors in $X$ have goats}, A \backslash X \neq \varnothing \text{ and } \overline{A} \backslash X \neq \varnothing  \},
$$
do my formulae work?

Another remaining question is, what is the general solution under Condition ($\alpha$) or Condition ($\beta$)?